# Create procedure where table owner, name and row is passed as parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to create a Procedure in Oracle PL/SQL where I pass the table owner's name, the table name and the column name to the procedure, so that I can print it to the screen.

The base of the procedure would be:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE table_printer(owner VARCHAR, table_name VARCHAR, column_name VARCHAR)
IS
...
```

My base idea was to pass it to a CURSOR inside the procedure but I learnt that you cannot really do that and I cannot seem to find the dynamic way of it.

My optimum result would be to iterate through the cursor of the given parameters and print out each row.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: When you say "print it to the screen" are you talking about the UI or just the console? In general a procedure can only provide a result to the caller (maybe a JSON result?) so the UI can display it.

Comment: Simple dbms_output.put_line();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd think of a function that returns e.g. ref cursor which actually can be used elsewhere. With a `dbms_output.put_line`, you can use it only with tools that support it (e.g. SQL*Plus or SQL Developer); in other tools (e.g. Oracle Apex or Forms), you wouldn't see *anything*.

Here's an example: dynamic SQL it is. `dbms_assert` is used to prevent SQL injection.

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test
  2    (par_owner in varchar2, par_table_name in varchar2, par_column_name in varchar2)
  3    return sys_refcursor
  4  is
  5    l_str varchar2(200);
  6    rc    sys_refcursor;
  7  begin
  8    l_str := 'select ' || dbms_assert.simple_sql_name (par_column_name) ||
  9             ' from '  || dbms_assert.schema_name     (par_owner)       ||'.'||
 10                          dbms_assert.sql_object_name (par_table_name);
 11    open rc for l_str;
 12    return rc;
 13  end;
 14  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_test('SCOTT', 'DEPT', 'DNAME') result from dual;

RESULT
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

DNAME
--------------
ACCOUNTING
RESEARCH
SALES
OPERATIONS


SQL>
```

---

**[EDIT: if it has to be `dbms_output.put_line`, then ...]**

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test
  2    (par_owner in varchar2, par_table_name in varchar2, par_column_name in varchar2)
  3  is
  4    l_str   varchar2(200);
  5    rc      sys_refcursor;
  6    --
  7    l_dname dept.dname%type;
  8  begin
  9    l_str := 'select ' || dbms_assert.simple_sql_name (par_column_name) ||
 10             ' from '  || dbms_assert.schema_name     (par_owner)       ||'.'||
 11                          dbms_assert.sql_object_name (par_table_name);
 12    open rc for l_str;
 13    loop
 14      fetch rc into l_dname;
 15      exit when rc%notfound;
 16      dbms_output.put_line(l_dname);
 17    end loop;
 18  end;
 19  /

Procedure created.

SQL> exec p_test('SCOTT', 'DEPT', 'DNAME');
ACCOUNTING
RESEARCH
SALES
OPERATIONS

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: This answer would be really good, but I really need to put everything into a single procedure. That is what my "task" is.

Comment: Basically the whole idea I'm looking for right now is that how can I iterate through a cursor that I just made explicitly ( with the open for statement ) in the same procedure where I want to iterate.

Comment: If you insist ... OK; have a look at edited answer.

Comment: Heyy! Thank you very much for the answer. I'm gonna mark it solved because basically you answered my question. I'm only left with one big question mark in this whole topic. So when you created the procedure you had to create a type where you exactly indicated which table, and column you want to use later on.

What if I know literally nothing about the table, owner, nor the column name so in that in that case the type should look like something like this: l_dname p_owner.p_table.p_column%type;

Comment: The first option I suggested uses a (weak) ref cursor which doesn't care about column names or their datatypes. As you said you don't want that option, I moved on to a procedure. Ref cursor is still OK (as it previously was), but - in order to display value(s) it fetched from the table, you have to put those values *into something* - a locally declared variable, and it has to have some datatype. If you declared it as e.g. `l_dname varchar2(255);`, you'd most probably be able to put numerous values into it (as Oracle would perform implicit conversion).